# Google Maps/Google Places: Is there a difference between getPlace and getDetails method?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

From reading the Google Docs, it seems like there is a difference, but when I call the methods, the returning object is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding no information online, I ran a serious of tests and even though Google does not explain it anywhere, I found that both the methods return the same object.